# Как выполнить команду параллельно?

Tags: c#, консоль

Есть консольное приложение, которое может запускать другие консольные приложение и перехватывать вывод от них.

```
    using (Process process = new Process())
    {

        process.StartInfo.FileName = "t-old.exe";
        process.StartInfo.Arguments = string.Join(" ", args);
        process.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
        process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = false;
        process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        process.Start();
        var streamIn = process.StandardInput;
        streamIn.Write(7);
        streamIn.Close();
        process.WaitForExit(); 
    }
```

Как не дожидаясь завершения работы приложения, периодически выполнять какую-нибудь функцию?

Comment: Например, в другом потоке

Comment: Уйтите вы от потоков и процессов. Используйте Task https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/12.2.php

Comment: .NET Framework или .NET 5?

Comment: В коде последняя строка явно ждет завершения работы процесса. Не потоки и Task тут нужны, а просто убрать WaitForExit.